# How many partitions can I create on my hard disk?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

How many partitions can I create in my hard disk? I have now 4 partitions, and the 5th partition is not allowed.

I currently have:

- 104 MB for Windows system
- 20.98 GB for ubuntu,
- C for Windows
- D for Windows

But I also now have the fifth partition (38 GB) which is not formatted. Can I add that place for my Ubuntu (33GB), and swap place (5GB)?

Now I am using both Windows and Ubuntu without problems but I have this free space doing nothing, and it is shown black in Windows partition window.

Answer (score 4):

This depends on what partition scheme you are using. The traditional approach (MBR partitioning) only allows 4 primary partitions. The trick is to create one of the four as an extended partition and then create further [logical partitions](http://pcguide.com/ref/hdd/file/structPartitions-c.html) within that.

The more modern GPT partitioning scheme allows as many partitions as you like. To test which of the two you have, run

```
sudo parted -l
```

Look in the output for a line like this:

```
Partition Table: msdos
```

The line above means the disk is using an MBR scheme. If you are using GPT instead, you'll see:

```
Partition Table: gpt
```

You can read more about the differences [here](http://www.partition-table.com/partition-table/mbr-gpt.php).

Answer (score 2):

Based on the description (namely, the fact that it's a Windows boot disk that has no EFI System Partition), the disk is almost certainly MBR (aka MS-DOS, BIOS, or various other terms), which has the 4-partition limit that terdon describes.

You can convert a partition from primary to logical form using various programs. My [FixParts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/), which is part of the `gdisk` package in Ubuntu, can do this, albeit with some caveats -- see the FixParts documentation for details. Some commercial Windows programs can also do this, but I don't know the details.

Incidentally, I believe that you do *not* "have the fifth part(38 GB) which is not formatted to anything." You've got 38 GB of *unpartitioned space* -- that is, space that's not claimed by any partition in the partition table. The partition table describes partitions, and it's possible for the partition table to become full before the disk does, in which case you'll have unpartitioned space that you can't use except by resizing partitions or jumping through hoops like a primary-to-logical conversion.

Comment: +1 for writing FixParts which I'd never heard of and which looks excellent. What makes you think the OP has a Windows 8 system though?

Comment: Rod exactly i have 38 GB "unpartitioned space" .Can i add it to ubuntu space.and i also dont have swap space.please help me.But both of my systems work well :)

Comment: terdon, I never said I thought the system was Windows 8. I said I thought it used MBR, and as I wrote, the reason is that there's no ESP mentioned in the description. An ESP is required to boot in EFI mode, and booting Windows in EFI mode requires use of GPT; hence, *if* the partition description is accurate and complete, and *if* Windows is booting from the disk, the disk uses MBR.

Comment: Sorry, dunno where I got that windows 8 from. I was assuming that this: `partitions:104MB for windows system,` meant the ESP.

Comment: terdon, you might be right. That's why I hate going on verbal descriptions; I prefer seeing the output of a program I know and understand, like `parted`, `fdisk`, or `gdisk`.